# Recursive menu is wrong level ordered

Tags: c#, list, tree, nodes, recursive-datastructures

Trying to build recursive menu with C#. The menu I need is as follows:

. Clients
. . . . Client 1
. . . . Client 3
. Company
. . . . Vision
. . . . . . . Short Statement
. . . . Who We Are
. . . . . . . Contact Us
. . . . . . . Team
. . . . . . . . . . Write To Us
. . . . . . . . . . . . . Media

But I'm getting:

> . Company
>   . . . . Vision
>   . . . . Who We Are
>   . . . . . . . Short Statement
>   . . . . . . . . . . Contact Us
>   . . . . . . . . . . Team
>   . . . . . . . . . . . . . Write To Us
>   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Media
>   . Clients
>   . . . . Client 1
>   . . . . Client 3

Some **corrections** need to be done so I need your help:

- Menu items should be ordered alphabetically; ex. Clients should be first then Company
- Some items are wrong level ordered and indented; ex. Short Statement should be after Vision and before Who We Are

So far I tried:

```
class Program
{
    public class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public List<Node<T>> Children { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node<T>>();
        }


        public List<Node<T>> LevelOrder()
        {
            List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
            Queue<Node<T>> queue = new Queue<Node<T>>();
            queue.Enqueue(this);
            while (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                Node<T> temp = queue.Dequeue();
                foreach (Node<T> child in temp.Children)
                    queue.Enqueue(child);
                list.Add(temp);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public List<Node<T>> PreOrder()
        {
            List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
            list.Add(this);
            foreach (Node<T> child in Children)
                list.AddRange(child.PreOrder());
            return list;
        }

        public List<Node<T>> PostOrder()
        {
            List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
            foreach (Node<T> child in Children)
                list.AddRange(child.PreOrder());
            list.Add(this);
            return list;
        }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string menuName { get; set; }
        public int? parentID { get; set; }
        public bool isHidden { get; set; }
        public string linkURL { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = @"ID;MenuName;ParentID;isHidden;Link
1;Company;NULL;False;/company
2;Who We Are;1;False;/company/whoweare
3;Vision;1;False;/company/vision
4;Team;2;False;/company/whoweare/team
5;Client 3;10;False;/clients/client3
6;Client 1;10;False;/clients/client1
7;Client 4;10;True;/clients/client4
8;Client 5;10;True;/clients/client5
10;Clients;NULL;False;/clients
11;Contact Us;2;False;/company/whoweare/contactus
12;Write To Us;4;False;/company/whoweare/team/writetous
13;Media;12;False;/company/whoweare/team/writetous/media
14;Short Statement;3;False;/company/vision/shortstatement";

        var lines = data.Split('\n');
        var rootNodes = new List<Node<Entity>>();
        var childItems = new List<Entity>();

        foreach (var row in lines.Skip(1))
        {
            var columns = row.Split(';');

            var id = Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]);
            var menuName = columns[1];
            var parentID = ToNullableInt(columns[2]);
            var isHidden = Convert.ToBoolean(columns[3]);
            var linkURL = columns[4];

            var entity = new Entity()
            {
                id = id,
                menuName = menuName,
                parentID = parentID,
                isHidden = isHidden,
                linkURL = linkURL
            };

            if (parentID == null)
            {
                rootNodes.Add(new Node<Entity>()
                {
                    Data = entity
                });
            }
            else
            {
                childItems.Add(entity);
            }
        }


        foreach (var rootNode in rootNodes)
        {
            foreach (var childItem in childItems.OrderBy(a => a.parentID).ThenBy(b => b.menuName))
            {
                var newNode = new Node<Entity>()
                {
                    Data = childItem
                };

                Insert(rootNode, newNode);
            }
        }

        foreach (var rootNode in rootNodes)
        {
            var indent = 0;
            var previous = rootNode;
            foreach (var node in rootNode.LevelOrder())
            {
                if (node.Data.isHidden) continue;

                if (previous.Data.parentID != node.Data.parentID)
                    indent++;

                for (var i = 0; i < indent; i++)
                    Console.Write(". . . ");

                Console.WriteLine(". " + node.Data.menuName);
                previous = node;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Insert(Node<Entity> rootNode, Node<Entity> targetNode)
    {
        foreach (var current in rootNode.LevelOrder())
        {
            if (current.Data.id == targetNode.Data.parentID)
            {
                current.Children.Add(targetNode);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int? ToNullableInt(string s)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to handle it like this ? I mean, i think it might be easier for you to save an ordinal number in the Entity, thus you don't need to do all this sorting and ordering each time. Is that possible for you ?

Comment: there is no a specific need @ShaiBarak, I have to get the menu as in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the PreOrder to work with a tuple of (level, item) like:

```
        public List<(int level, Node<T> item)> PreOrder(int level = 0)
        {
            List<(int level, Node<T> item)> list = new List<(int level, Node<T> item)>();
            list.Add((level, this));
            level += 1;
            foreach (Node<T> child in Children)
                list.AddRange(child.PreOrder(level));
            return list;
        }
```

and use it in your print section like (I have also added the order by menuName here):

```
        foreach (var rootNode in rootNodes.OrderBy(a => a.Data.menuName))
        {
            var indent = 0;
            foreach (var node in rootNode.PreOrder())
            {
                if (node.item.Data.isHidden)
                    continue;

                for (var i = 0; i < node.level; i++)
                    Console.Write(". . . ");

                Console.WriteLine(". " + node.item.Data.menuName);
            }
        }
```

that will return the menu in the same format that you have requested.